# Horizontal Align Navigational Toolbar with spacing

Tags: css, html

I am having difficulty knowing what to do to complete my toolbar...I feel I have everything but it is not actually aligning horizontally--inline--with spaces in between each tab. I would like it to look much like the toolbar on this site, but instead it is aligned two next to each other and then two on top of that.

Could someone tell me what I am missing? Thanks for any available help.

CSS:

```
.toolbar ul {
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     text-align:center;
     list-style-type:none;

}
.toolbar ul li {
     display:inline;

}
.toolbar ul li a {
     text-decoration:none;
     padding-right:30px;
     background-color:#990000;
     border-style:solid;
     border-color:#000000;
     border-width:1px; 
     padding:10px;
     font-family:"Gadget", sans-serif;
     font-size:14px;
     font-weight:bold;
     position:relative;
     top:100px;
     left:320px;
     vertical-align:bottom; 

}
a:link {
     color:#ffffff;
}
```

HTML5:

```
<div class="toolbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="content.html">Course Content</a></li>
    <li><a href="resources.html">Related Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="pilot.html">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want it top to bottom... on the center of the screen?

Comment: The code you have posted here has everything in a horizontal line with spacing inbetween (yes, moved quite a bit to the right).  Nothing is stacked on top of anything as far as I can see, so you will probably want to include more code to demonstrate.

Comment: @JeremyMiller that is what I was wondering... `display:inline;` is going to display the menu `inline`... pretty straight forward

Comment: @imbondbaby Right!  So unless something is around all of this and affecting it, your answer points out the only adjustment that can be made -- removing the seemingly-arbitrary movement to the right.  I don't see the reported error, though.

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is due to the fact that your tabs are inline displayed, so when you adjust the window width and it reaches a small size, the other tabs go below the other ones. One way to fix this is to use a fixed width for the toolbar.

[SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tk3Vj/)

```
.toolbar ul {
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     text-align:center;
     list-style-type:none;
    width: 800px;

}
```

Comment: Technically, assuming nothing else is going on on the page, this is correct.  However, the consequence is that after a certain width (800px in your case), navigation disappears.  Which is worse?  In today's world, responsive design is the answer.